# How to test Google Cloud Storage Triggers Cloud Function locally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, functions-framework

With reference to [Google Cloud Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) , I wrote a background function which gets triggered from GCS. Using [GCP Function Framework for Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-java), is it possible to test it locally ?

Answer (score -1):

You can test locally your Cloud Function triggers by running integration tests.

> Integration tests should trigger and respond to actual Cloud events
> such as HTTP requests, Pub/Sub messages, or Storage object changes.

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-basics#integration_tests)

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-background#storage-triggered_functions) you may find more information for testing background Cloud Functions.